# ファイル名を取得してサーブレットクラスに渡したい。

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

画面でテーブルに対して行をクリックし、黄色行になっている状態で「ファイル名取得ボタン」を押し、黄色行のファイル名をJavaのサーブレットクラスに渡したいと思います。テーブルに対して行をクリックし、黄色行にするとこまでできているのですが、ファイル名を取得してJavaのサーブレットクラスにファイル名を渡すコードをどう書くか分かりません。どう書けばよろしいでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>ファイルダウンロード</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sentaku(pos) {
        switch (pos) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("tr1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            document.getElementById("tr2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("tr2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            document.getElementById("tr1").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            break;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>ファイルダウンロード画面</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="download" action="/downloadfile" method="post">

            <table id="name_tbl" border="1" width="500" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="5" bordercolor="#333333">
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000"><font color="#FFFFFF">Ｎｏ</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="150"><font color="#FFFFFF">ファイル名</font></t    h>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="200"><font color="#FFFFFF">備考</font></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr1" onclick="sentaku(1)">
                    <td align="right" nowrap>１</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="150">aaa.text</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr2" onclick="sentaku(2)">
                    <td align="right" nowrap>２</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="150">bbb.text</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    type="submit">ファイル名取得ボタン</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

ざっくりと書いてみましたけど、こんな感じでどうでしょうか。
表の行をクリックした時点の行番号を保存（currentPos）しておきます。ファイル名取得ボタンを押したときに、その情報からファイル名を取得します。つづけて、そのファイル名をformのaction属性にセットしてフォームをsubmitしています。

Servletでは、downloadというURLのリクエストを受取、パラメーターfileNameからファイル名を受け取ることができます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>ファイルダウンロード</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var currentPos = -1;
    function sentaku(pos) {
        currentPos = pos;
        switch (pos) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("tr1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            document.getElementById("tr2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("tr2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            document.getElementById("tr1").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>ファイルダウンロード画面</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="download" action="/downloadfile" method="post">

            <table id="name_tbl" border="1" width="500" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="5" bordercolor="#333333">
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000"><font color="#FFFFFF">Ｎｏ</font></th>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="150"><font color="#FFFFFF">ファイル名</font></t    h>
                    <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="200"><font color="#FFFFFF">備考</font></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr1" onclick="sentaku(1)">
                    <td align="right" nowrap>１</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="150">aaa.text</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr2" onclick="sentaku(2)">
                    <td align="right" nowrap>２</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="150">bbb.text</td>
                    <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px">
                <button id="getFileName" class="btn btn-primary"
                    type="button">ファイル名取得ボタン</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("getFileName").addEventListener("click", function() {
        //ファイル名の取得
        var fileName = document.querySelector("#tr" + currentPos + " td:nth-child(2)").textContent;
        // formのactionにセットし、submit
        var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
        form.action = "dowonloadFile?fileName=" + fileName;
        form.submit();
    }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```